# Why System.SetLength(Str, Len) causes the address of Str changes?

Tags: delphi

#### Code Illustration

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Str: string;
  PStr: PChar;
begin
  Str := 'This a string.';
  PStr := Pointer(Str); // PStr holds the address of the first char of Str
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Longint(PStr))); // It displays e.g. 4928304

  Setlength(Str, 20);

  // I don't know what actually happens in the call for SetLength() above,
  // because the address of Str changes now, so the PStr not valid anymore.

  // This is a proof of the fact
  PStr := Pointer(Str);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Longint(PStr))); // It's now different, e.g. 11423804
end;
```

#### Question

1. Why `System.SetLength(Str, Len)` causes the address of *Str* changes?
2. Is there a way to nullify this side effect of `SetLength` so that I don't have to reassign the new address of *Str*  to *PStr* ?

Comment: The *address of* Str does not change. Str is a local variable, and it resides on the stack. Its address is constant for the duration of the subroutine. The address *stored in* Str changes. Being precise when you describe a problem will help you understand and solve a problem.

Comment: @Rob, sorry, would you explain more what you meant by "The address stored in Str changes"? So, its address didn't change but the constant. I'll be happy if you are please to edit my question properly.

Comment: By casting Str to a pointer, you read the address stored in Str. Not the address of Str (that would be @Str or Addr(Str)). The address stored in Str is the address of memory block used by the string (actually, the address of the first byte of the string, with string management data at negative offsets). Thereby to be precise the address of Str (@Str) does not change, it's the valued stored in it (pointer(Str)) that changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the [help on System.SetLength](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.SetLength) says "*Following a call to SetLength, S **is guaranteed to reference a unique string** or array—that is, a string or array with a reference count of one. If there is not enough memory available to reallocate the variable, SetLength raises an EOutOfMemory exception.*"

It always reallocates the string, that's why the address changes. It is also a way to get a string not used by anything else.

Update: to be fully correct, it's better to rephrase the statement above "it's safer to assume it always reallocates the sting". See comments below for an explanation.

Comment: It does NOT always reallocate a string, especially not when shrinking it. It will always reallocate it when the reference count to the string is higher than 1, granted.  But if the reference count is one, it will not be reallocated on a shrink. When the string need to grow, the system will first try to realloc the string "in place", and if it can't, will realloc it elsewhere. Basic testing is consistent with this...

Comment: When refcount is 1, it will call _ReallocMem (check the source). What happens there depends on the implementation of _ReallocMem, which is memory manager specific. It can shrink/expand in place, it can move the memory if it thinks it's better to do so. Beware of basic testing... It's much safer to assume the string is always reallocated, or you may end up with very subtle bugs to trace.

Comment: @Kennedy: what happend with FastMM if I shrink a 16MB string to a 16 byte one? Will it change what pool the memory comes from? For example you can find comments like this: {In-place downsize? Balance the cost of moving the data vs. the cost of fragmenting the memory pool.} Beware that even a shrink may move the memory block. Never believe it won't. Relying on it is simply dangerous. IMHO if the string is not reallocated is an "eception", not the rule.

Comment: Whether a downsize is done in-place depends on how much smaller it's getting. For small blocks, the threshold is 75%; for medium and large blocks, 50%. If the new requested size is below the threshold, then it will allocate a new block (i.e., the address will change), else it will stay in the current block. If the new size is small enough, then a large or medium block may be copied into a medium or small block; if `FastReallocMem` needs a new block, it goes through `FastGetMem`, just like any other allocation. The bottom line is it's incorrect to say `SetLength` *always* reallocates.

Comment: In fact I've update my answer to say "it's safer to assume it always reallocates". From application code is very difficult to tell when it will be reallocated and when it is not. The memory manager manager or its algorithm may change, and relying on actual (and any undocumented) behaviour is IMHO too risky.

Answer (score 8):

I don't use Delphi but, clearly, the address changes when more memory must be allocated (e.g. the string needs to get bigger).

Since a string may not have any free space past the memory being used, it would be impossible to make a string longer without ever moving it.

You need to keep your reassignment.

Comment: No. The memory changes every time you call SetLength(), even if it shrinks the string. It is the documented behaviour. Because Delphi strings use a "copy-on-write" mechanism, modifying the string length is a kind of "write", because other code referencing the string needs to be protected from those changes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you point to where I said it will not move when shrinking? Because I don't see it. In fact, I specifically stated I don't use Delphi. What I know and said was that it is not possible to devise a practical allocation scheme that will never move the memory. If Delphi always reallocates when the string size changes, that doesn't conflict with anything I've said.

Comment: As you said, you don't use Delphi and don't know how Delphi strings are implemented. Your answer is half correct (or one third, maybe). Because there are other reasons why the memory the string variable points to is reallocated. Even if the string size does not change. Write S := 'FOOBAR'; A := S; SetLength(S, Length(S)); and A and S will point to different memory. Your answer does not explain this.

Comment: @User160694 I disagree. In terms of the question (which shows string set to a longer length) this answer is 100% correct. This answer clearly points out that any expectation to increase the size of something in place is fundamentally flawed. (I.e. If it happens, you were lucky to save a few clock cycles bc the data did not need to be copied to its new location.) The other aspects are interesting additional information about other things that _may_ cause the address to change - even if the new length is the same or smaller.

Answer (score 4):

No per Jonathan Wood, and additionally please note that not only length, every time you do *anything* with the string (even trim it) you have to be ready that it's address changes.

This is because when you copy a string:

```
var s1, s2: string;
begin
  s1 := 'test'+IntToStr(SomeNumber);
  s2 := s1;
```

Delphi actually copies just a reference, but increments reference counter. s1 and s2 now point to the same memory, but Delphi "remembers" that this memory is used from two places.

If you now try to trim s1:

```
SetLength(s1, 4);
```

Delphi figures s2 needs to stay unchanged, and so it does not trim s1 inplace, but instead copies four bytes to a new place. You now have s1 and s2 pointing to different memory adresses, each with reference counter of 1.

You usually cannot and should not try to predict when this will happen, just remember that the pointer to the string is valid only while the string stays unchanged.

Comment: Afaik the string [] operator is unchecked in anyway, including this one

Comment: @Marco, assigning to a string character via the bracket operators will cause the string to be re-allocated if it has a reference count other than 1. The compiler will insert calls to `UniqueString` to make sure that happens.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is inherent to Delphi's String type.

If you want a consistent address use a PChar instead of String.

Comment: If you reallocate a pointer to a new size, the address might also change for exactly the same reasons.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question...

1.Like ldsandon stated, SetLength guarantee the string will reference a unique string. Since you variable is assigned a constant string, the said string must have a reference count of at least 2 and thus can't realloc the memory in-place.
If your string was initialized by, for exemple, `StringOfChar('A',5)`, the address of your string might not change after `SetLength` (Though it wouldn't be guaranteed)

2.No, I don't think so. It's like asking for the following:

```
  procedure someproc
  var Obj1, obj2 : TObject;
  begin
  [...]
    obj2 := Obj1;
    Obj1 := nil;
    //I want Obj2 to be also nil here since obj1 is nil...
  end;
```

if you really want to be absolutely sure the address of PStr is the same as the string, there is 2 options I can think of right now, neither of which I can really recommend.

First:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Str: string;
  PStr: PChar absolute Str;
begin
```

But here, do NOT modify PStr as it will break the Str variable.

Second:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Str: string;
  function PStr: PChar
  begin
    Result := PChar(Str);
  end
begin
```

But it's always better to just use "PChar(Str)" wherever you need to access your string as a Pchar.

Also, don't forger that if you write to the string through a PChar variable, you should ensure that the string has a reference count of 1 first(By calling UniqueString or SetLength).

Comment: I test the `PStr: PChar absolute Str` statement, but `PStr' still become invalid after `SetLength`.

Comment: String literals have a reference count of -1, not 2.